# script taking lot of time to give the output

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

m doing lot of calculations to get the result.. since m running all the queries inside while loop its taking lot of time to give the result.. its taking nearly 1min..can anyone suggent me ideas how to get result faster..my code is as follows

```
<table style="font-size:13px" width="150%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
<tr bgcolor="#0063F5" align="center" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:16px;color:#FFF; font-weight:bold;">
    <td colspan="29">Post Service Feedback Report For <?=$empLocationName ?> Location</td>
    </tr>
       <tr bgcolor="#D3E6F3" style=" color:#009; font-weight:bold" align="center">
    <td >Engineer Name</td>
    <!--<td>Location</td>-->
    <td>Total Repairs</td>
    <td>Total PSF Recieved</td>
    <td>Total PSF Recieved %</td>
    <td colspan="4">Technical Ability</td>
    <td  colspan="4">Professionalism</td>
    <td colspan="4">Quality of Repair</td>
    <td colspan="4">Overall Satisfaction</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#D3E6F3" style=" color:#009; font-weight:bold" align="center">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Sat</td>
  <td>Sat %</td>
  <td>D-Sat</td>
  <td>D-Sat %</td>
      <td>Sat</td>
  <td>Sat %</td>
  <td>D-Sat</td>
  <td>D-Sat %</td>

    <td>Sat</td>
  <td>Sat %</td>
  <td>D-Sat</td>
  <td>D-Sat %</td>

    <td>Sat</td>
  <td>Sat %</td>
  <td>D-Sat</td>
  <td>D-Sat %</td>  
  </tr>
  <?
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($total_repairs)){

      $engineer=$row['empName'];
      $location=$row['locationName'];
      $repairs=mysql_query("select count(ackNo) as tot from tblRepairQueue where assignedTo='".$engineer."' and month(ClosedAt)='".$month."' and YEAR(ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
      $tot_repairs=mysql_fetch_array($repairs);
     $feedback_rec=mysql_query("select count(callStatus) as feedback from ContactCenter where callStatus='Close' and assignedTo='".$engineer."'  and month(ClosedAt)='".$month."' and YEAR(ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
      $tot_feedback=mysql_fetch_array($feedback_rec);
      $techsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.technical ) as tech_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.technical in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
       $tech_sat=mysql_fetch_array($techsat);
       $techdsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.technical ) as tech_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.technical in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
       $tech_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($techdsat);
       $profsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.prof ) as prof_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.prof in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $prof_sat=mysql_fetch_array($profsat);
        $profdsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.prof ) as prof_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.prof in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and  ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $prof_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($profdsat);
        /*$ressat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.res ) as res_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.res in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."' ");
       $res_sat=mysql_fetch_array($ressat);
        $resdsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.res ) as res_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.res in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $res_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($resdsat);*/
        $qttysat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.qtty ) as qtty_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.qtty in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $qtty_sat=mysql_fetch_array($qttysat);
         $qttydsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.qtty ) as qtty_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.qtty in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $qtty_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($qttydsat);
       /* $timesat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.tim ) as time_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.tim in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'   and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $time_sat=mysql_fetch_array($timesat);
        $timedsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.tim ) as time_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.tim in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $time_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($timedsat);*/
         $overallsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.overall ) as overall_sat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.overall in (1,2)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.callStatus='Close' and ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $overall_sat=mysql_fetch_array($overallsat);
         $overalldsat=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( CustomerFeed.overall ) as overall_dsat FROM ContactCenter, CustomerFeed WHERE CustomerFeed.overall in (4,5)  AND CustomerFeed.callId = ContactCenter.callId AND ContactCenter.assignedTo = '".$engineer."' and month(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$month."'  and YEAR(ContactCenter.ClosedAt)='".$year."'");
       $overall_dsat=mysql_fetch_array($overalldsat);
      ?>
      <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
      <td align="left"><?=$engineer?></td>

      <td><? if($tot_repairs['tot']!='0') { echo $tot_repairs['tot']; } else { echo "-"; }?></td>
      <td><? if($tot_feedback['feedback']!='0') { echo $tot_feedback['feedback']; } else { echo "-"; } ?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($tot_feedback['feedback']/$tot_repairs['tot'])*100);?></td>
      <td><? if($tech_sat['tech_sat']!='0') { echo $tech_sat['tech_sat']; } else echo "-";?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($tech_sat['tech_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
      <td><? if($tech_dsat['tech_dsat']!='0'){ echo $tech_dsat['tech_dsat']; } else echo "-";?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($tech_dsat['tech_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
      <td><? if($prof_sat['prof_sat']!='0') { echo $prof_sat['prof_sat']; } else { echo "-"; }?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($prof_sat['prof_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
      <td><? if($prof_dsat['prof_dsat']!='0'){ echo $prof_dsat['prof_dsat']; } else  echo "-";?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($prof_dsat['prof_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
      <!-- <td><?=$res_sat['res_sat']?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($res_sat['res_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
      <td><?=$res_dsat['res_dsat']?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($res_dsat['res_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>-->


      <td><? if($qtty_sat['qtty_sat']!='0'){ echo $qtty_sat['qtty_sat']; } else echo "-";?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($qtty_sat['qtty_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
       <td><? if($qtty_dsat['qtty_dsat']!='0') { echo $qtty_dsat['qtty_dsat'];} else echo "-";?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($qtty_dsat['qtty_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
        <!--<td><?=$time_sat['time_sat']?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($time_sat['time_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
       <td><?=$time_dsat['time_dsat']?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($time_dsat['time_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>-->
      <td><? if($overall_sat['overall_sat']!='0'){ echo $overall_sat['overall_sat'];} else echo "-";?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($overall_sat['overall_sat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
      <td><? if($overall_dsat['overall_dsat']!='0'){ echo $overall_dsat['overall_dsat']; } else echo "-";?></td>
      <td><? echo round(($overall_dsat['overall_dsat']/$tot_feedback['feedback'])*100); ?></td>
      </tr>
 <? }
  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You probably have to re-think the way you create the statistics. Did you count how many rows you are actually reading each time the page is displayed?

Comment: @opalenzuela it will read nearly 15 rows..is it delaying becoz the queries are inside while loop?

Comment: Wrong: each time you put a COUNT() query, it's reading all the rows. I see 10 counts, and they are **inside a while loop!!!**

Comment: 10 Queries on each run of the loop, lets say the loop runs 100 times then that makes it a 1000 queries per page load, how much time that is supposed to take then ?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky i can understand that..but i need assigned to which gives list of persons name suppose 10 persons..so for each person i need to calculate things..so m making use of this inside while loop

Comment: Rationalise some of those database queries to reduce their number: e.g combine the `$qttysat` and `$profsat` queries into single query; likewise with `$qttydsat` and `$profdsat`

Comment: omg. very readable I have to say, everyone will understand this code instantly. The only acceptable answer would be "Rewrite the whole script."

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql_fetch_rows instead of mysql_fetch_array. And apply indexing on columns. It will decrease some exectution time

Answer (score 0):

you use ternory operator for fast execution rather than if else  and also make a function for seperate query .

Like